# How to store Date from C# to MS-Access and how to retrieve it?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, devexpress

I used dateEdit field to store date in my form. In Access Database it store as "07-01-2014" but When I try to retrieve it back to dateEdit field, it displaying "07-01-2014 AM 12:00:00". I dont need time. How to remove this time from dateEdit Field.

Comment: What is `dateEdit` field? Anyway, check it properties, to see if you can specify format (mask?) for it.

Comment: DateEdit is a control to display date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved that by simple changing DateTime datatype to string in both C# and MS-Access database. Now am getting Date only.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q391736) in the DevExpress support forum the solution would be to set the `DateEdit.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat` property to `True`. For more information see

[MaskProperties.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskProperties_UseMaskAsDisplayFormattopic)

Answer (score 1):

For retrieve only date:

```
DateTime retDate= *retrieved date*;
string onlyDate = retDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```